# Is it impossible to dynamically create secure hosted PayPal buttons?

Tags: php, security, paypal

I know how to create a hosted button on PayPal, and I know this is secure, and I can integrate it with my cart for it to work.

But I need to dynamically create a hosted, secure button PayPal because I need to update the price for this button dynamically.

Basically I just want a dynamic version of the hosted secure buttons, without having to personally add any encryption or IPN or what have you. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't be an issue.  You can create dynamic hosted buttons on the fly using the BMCreateButton API.  You can find more about this [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/bmcreatebutton-api-operation-nvp), and you can also view the developers guide [here](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_wpsbuttonmgrapinvp.pdf) as well.